# Trying to create Lightbox gallery for only one foreach element

Tags: php, jquery, html, curl

Okay, so here's what I'm trying to achieve!

I have a PHP script that I pull information into a foreach() statement from an API/JSON setup.

This is some of my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$category=$_GET['category'];
$url="http://www.someurl.com/api/listings?token=f716909f5d644fe3702be5c7895aa34e&group_id=10046&species=".$category;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept: application/json',
'X-some-API-Key: f716909f5d644fe3702be5c7895aa34e',
));
$json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);

// Functions relating to the Echo Code

foreach($json['listings'] as $listing)
{
$short_personality=substr($listing['personality'],0,500);
$peturl="http://www.someurl.com/?variable=".$listing['id'];
$medium_photo=$listing['photos'][0]['large_340'];
$gender_class=strtolower($listing['gender']);
$breed_class=strtolower($listing['species']);
$name=($listing['name']);
```

Then, I'm creating the image to display with the following code:

```
// Echo the output

echo'<div class="animal">
        <div class="animal-image">';
        if ($listing['photos'] > 1) {
    echo '<a class="size-thumbnail thickbox" rel="gallery" href="'.$medium_photo.'">
                <img src="'.$medium_photo.'" class="image-with-border" alt="">
                <div class="border" style="width: 340px; height: 340px;">
                    <div class="open"></div>
                </div>
            </a>';
        }
else {
    echo '<a class="size-thumbnail thickbox" href="'.$medium_photo.'">
                <img src="'.$medium_photo.'" class="image-with-border" alt="">
                <div class="border" style="width: 340px; height: 340px;">
                    <div class="open"></div>
                </div>
            </a>';
}
```

So, for example, the API pulls in 25 items that are all formatted into their individual section, each section has it's own initial photo.  When I click on that photo, the lightbox loads.

BUT, it loads the lightbox for ALL images in the API call, so I'm getting 144 images available in the lightbox.

Is there a way to limit the photos in the lightbox for each item that's being retrieved?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: by saying *it loads the lightbox for ALL images in the API call, so I'm getting 144 images available in the lightbox* you mean that when you turn the wheel in your mouse or push the arrow keys you are viewing the next one like all images are in one gallery?

Comment: what is the name of the plugin? thickbox?

Comment: Due to this being used in a Wordpress site, it uses a modified version of Thickbox: https://codex.wordpress.org/ThickBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*this answer is based on my assumption that you use [thickbox plugin](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/) (if thats the case please update your question details :D )*

if you want every image to be "alone" and not in a gallery then every link must have a different `rel="name-of-individual-image-gallery-whatever"`

so you can do something like

```
// Functions relating to the Echo Code

// add a counter
$inc=0;

foreach($json['listings'] as $listing)
{
    $short_personality=substr($listing['personality'],0,500);
    $peturl="http://www.someurl.com/?variable=".$listing['id'];
    $medium_photo=$listing['photos'][0]['large_340'];
    $gender_class=strtolower($listing['gender']);
    $breed_class=strtolower($listing['species']);
    $name=($listing['name']);
    // add this
    $unique_gallery_name="individual-gallery-".$inc;
    $inc++;
    // the rest of your code...
    // .
    // .
    // .
```

and then add that `rel` attribute to your output code

`<a class="size-thumbnail thickbox" rel="'.$unique_gallery_name.'"`

so each link will have one rel like this `rel="individual-gallery-0"`, the next link `rel="individual-gallery-1"`, the next link `rel="individual-gallery-2"` ... and so on. The result will be every image to be in a "unique" gallery, "alone"

Comment: Thanks Sharky!  That did the trick.  Now I just need to loop through the photos for each listing.  Thanks for your help!